# selenium with python doesn't fill a dropdown out when passing as dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, web2py

i have this function to fill webfroms using selenium

```
def fill_form(self, action, dict):
        import time
        print "Starting %s ... \n" % action

        # fill the form
        for key in dict.keys():
            try:
                inputElement = self._driver.find_element_by_name(key)
                inputElement.clear()
                inputElement.send_keys(dict[key])
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except:
                self.log()
                pass
```

of course this function is a part of class

well with this function selenium ignore any dropdown menu, and therefor i have to fill each dropdown then always using the normal statement ***but before the loop*** for example:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name('dropdownMenu')
inputElement.send_keys('Test')
object.fill_form('action here', dict)
```

i tried to use the loop without the function but it gives the same result, the problem is the loop!

i get also many exceptions in the log file

```
[2013-14-01 21:51:55] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException(), <traceback object at 0x0212BFA8>)
[2013-14-01 21:52:04] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException(), <traceback object at 0x021372B0>)
[2013-14-01 21:52:04] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>, NoSuchElementException(), <traceback object at 0x021431C0>)
[2013-14-01 21:52:51] (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException(), <traceback object at 0x0212FE90>)
```

---

***the full class***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
 *                                                                   *
 * PyWebBot Automated Web Tasks based on Selenium using dictionaries *
 *                                                                   *
Features:
    (1) - Login function
    (2) - Visit Link
    (3) - Make Screenshot
    (4) - Fill and sumbit forms

Filename:   ClassPyWebBot
Author:     Isaak Wahb (Wahb Ben Ishak)
Contact:    ben.ishak@tum.de

Date:       2012-08-15
Version:    1.0
Licence:    GPL v2

Usage:
    bot = PyWebBot([Selenium Webdriver] driver,
                   [dict(username,password)] user,
                   [String] _LogPath,
                   [String] _ScreenshotPath)

    bot.run([String] action, 
            [dict] dict,
            [String] baseurl,
            [String] suburl)

"""

class PyWebBot():
    """
    PyWebBot Automated Web Tasks Class
    """

    def __init__(self,_driver, _user, _LogPath, _ScreenshotPath):
        object.__init__(self)
        self._driver = _driver
        self._user = _user
        self._LogPath = _LogPath
        self._ScreenshotPath = _ScreenshotPath
        pass

    def log(self):
        import time, sys, os
        path = os.path.join(self._LogPath)
        logfile = os.path.join(path,'error_log').replace(os.sep,'/')
        time_x = time.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
        with open(logfile,'a') as log:
            return log.write("[%s] %s\n" % (time_x, str(sys.exc_info()).strip()))

    def screenshot(self, imgname):
        import os, time
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            self._driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.path.join(self._ScreenshotPath,imgname))
        except:
            self.log()
            pass

    def login(self):
        import time
        try:
            inputElement = self._driver.find_element_by_name('username')
            inputElement.send_keys(self._user['username'])
            inputElement = self._driver.find_element_by_name('password')
            inputElement.send_keys(self._user['password'])
            self.screenshot('user_login_%s__%s.png' % (self._user['username'], time.time()))
            inputElement.submit()
        except:
            self.log()
            pass

    def visit_link(self, baseurl, suburl):
        import time
        try:
            self._driver.get("%s/%s" %(baseurl, suburl))
            # Capture screen after visit
            self.screenshot('visted_link_%s_%s__%s.png' % (suburl.replace('/','_'), self._user['username'], time.time()))
        except:
            self.log()
            pass

    def fill_form(self, action, dict):
        import time
        print "Starting %s ... \n" % action

        # fill the form
        for key in dict.keys():
            try:
                inputElement = self._driver.find_element_by_name(key)
                inputElement.clear()
                inputElement.send_keys(dict[key])
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except:
                self.log()
                pass

        # capture screen before
        self.screenshot('%s_%s__%s.png' % (action, self._user['username'], time.time()))

        # submit the form
        try:
            inputElement.submit()
        except:
            pass

        # Capture screen after submit
        self.screenshot('%s_%s_submited__%s.png' % (action, self._user['username'], time.time()))

        print "%s done.\n" % action

    def run(self, action , dict, baseurl, suburl, login=True):
        try:
            # Visit link
            self.visit_link(baseurl, suburl)

            # need to login ?
            if login: self.login()

            # Fill form
            self.fill_form(action, dict)

            # Close driver
            print "Finished\n"
            self._driver.close()
            pass
        except:
            self.log()
            print "Error ... check error_log"
```

Comment: There are a pile of problems and questionable things going on in this code.  Can you provide more of your code so we can see the context and fix the underlying design problems here?  Otherwise we are just putting a bandaid over something that needs surgery.

Comment: only that part doesn't even when i use ***simple code*** (without class, without function) ***just puting the loop*** and giving it a dictionary, dropdown menu stills excepted!

Comment: Well, you are getting `NoSuchElement` exceptions, so clearly, if your code is working one way and not the other, you aren't using the same data for your element selectors, in the least.

Comment: @sr2222 > check the wohle class